# Eclipse Indigo and GWT: Unable to read repository

Tags: eclipse, gwt, repository

This is a bit of a repost but the solutions proposed in the posts I found previously did not work for me, so I thought I might just as well start a new discusion.

I have a new Eclipse Indigo and I want to install the GWT-Plugin. I am running java Runtime Environment build 1.7.0.01 on a Windows OS (64 bit). The Eclipse is also the 64 bit version. I execute eclipse as administrator (but the same problem pops up if I don't).

Eclipse is told to juse java 1.6 as a compiler (since I hear there are issues with 1.7 and GWT).

So I click Help>>Install New Software and put in http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7 as a source. This then takes forever (Fetching Children of GWT) resulting in:

"Unable to read repository at http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7/content.jar.
Unable to read repository at http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7/content.jar.
Read timed out" as an error.

I have tried this all day. Once I at least could read the repository but could not install because of some unsatisfied dependencies. But that was on another eclipse distribution if I remember correctly.

So generally I don't seem to have any luck with GWT.

I would be greatfull for any advice to get GWT running. thanks.

**Edit** googled further, found a blog entry that told me to update to java 1.7.0_04. did that. no change.

**Edit2** On the assumtion, that it is in fact not my eclipse but the google servers, I used the download of the plugin (as sugested by kush in the comments). This gets me to this screen https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDmyr.png but not that much closer to the solutiuon.

"Cannot complete the install because one ore more required items could not be found."

I have tried this with Indigo and Helios, the ruslts are similar.

Comment: Hey Lukas, this may sound silly but please hear me through. Try  installing only the bare minimum of the stuff you need. Skip out on the android stuff that dl.google.com tries to push at you. It has resolved the issue for me in the past. Let me know if that helps. (Either way, I think it is worth a try while someone comes up with a solution.)

Comment: I would absolutly give that a try as soon as I get that far, right now it never finishes to even fetch and just tells me, that it could not read the repository.

Comment: Very strange indeed. So you never see this screen? http://i.imgur.com/i3ovg.png

Comment: nope, I see this http://i.imgur.com/C5AoY.png

Comment: this at least gives me that screen. Should I install GWT Designer for GPE (its recomedet, but also, might be the problem...)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7242/discussion-between-kush-and-lukas-ruge)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took a while (three days) but the answer is as easy as it is strange: Do not use the 64 bit version of eclipse.

I would apreciate if someone finds out what the problem with the 64 bit versions is, but as soon as I started using the 32 bit version (which works fine on the 64 bit windows) everything installed perfectly.

Anyway, hope to help somone else with this post.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this issue for days now. I cannot get the GWT eclipse plugin installed on my laptop. I am using the 32 bit version of eclipse. Plus, I can install the plugin just fine on the 64bit version of Eclipse on my PC, so I know that is not the issue.

Finally! I solved this.

Had to completely uninstall JRE 7 then everything installed fine.